# Unable to run Java code with Apache Commons

Tags: java, apache, runtimeexception

I've written a program to read in data from a text file and do some simple calculations, then print out those calculations. That part works great.

Afterward, I added in some code to do a t-test, using the TTest class (org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest). So, I downloaded commons-math3-3.6.jar from the Apache Commons download page and put the JAR file in the same folder as the rest of my Java code for this program.

I use the following command in Windows to compile, which works fine:

`javac -cp ./commons-math3-3.6.jar ./FootballTeam.java ./Main.java`

But I can't figure out how to correctly run the program. I've tried this:

`java Main`

which executes everything up to the t-test perfectly, and then gives the expected error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/math3/stat/inference/TTest
        at Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.math3.stat.inference.TTest
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more`

I've also tried this:

`java -cp commons-math3-3.6.jar Main`

which gives me this:

`Error: Could not find or load main class Main`

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to properly set the classpath here. Can someone provide me some assistance? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Main` class cannot be found because the current directory (`.`) is not on your classpath.

To add it, on Windows:

```
java -cp ".;commons-math3-3.6.jar" Main
```

On *n?x:

```
java -cp ".:commons-math3-3.6.jar" Main
```

Comment: Oh my freaking god. The instructions I was given was to do ".:" only, and so I never tried ".;" because I didn't know about it. Such a simple solution! Thank you!